# The toArrray function is not working properly while using for MERN STACK project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

[This the output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mt916.png)
I am following a YouTube tutorial for MERN stack project while following the playlist I have got stuck at one instance. Please help!!

**db.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoURI = 'mongodb://<username>:<password>@ac-czejupk-shard-00-00.e8wdets.mongodb.net:27017,ac-czejupk-shard-00-01.e8wdets.mongodb.net:27017,ac-czejupk-shard-00-02.e8wdets.mongodb.net:27017/?ssl=true&replicaSet=atlas-11o3y9-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority'
const mongoDB =async()=>{
   await mongoose.connect(mongoURI, { useNewUrlParser: true }, async (err, result) => {
        if (err) console.log("---", err);
        else {
            console.log("connected");
            const fetched_data = await mongoose.connection.db.collection("food_items");
            
            
            
     
           fetched_data.find({}).toArray(function(err, data) {
                    if (err) console.log(err);
                    else {
                        global.food_items = data;
                        console.log(global.food_items);
                    };
    
                });
           
            
            
            

        }

    });
}

module.exports = mongoDB;
```

This is the code in which i am facing issue I have deployed database on mongodb under name "food_items" after the execution of the "console.log(global.food_items)" it should have given me the list of all items in "food_items" but the output which I am getting is empty list please help.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-validator": "^7.0.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.12",
    "mongodb-legacy": "^6.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.6.1",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "react-jwt": "^1.2.0"
  }
}
```